# How to force geopandas to plot a map with "missing values" (legend) in a columns without "missing values"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, matplotlib-basemap

I want to make some maps (each column is a date), and for some columns (aka dates) there are some missing values, and for others are not. When I used the function within geopandas "missing_kwds" to highlight missing values (for some regions). When there are NaNs values in the columns (date) the code works fine, but when there are no NaNs in the column I got an Error saying "local variable 'merged_kwds' referenced before assignment". Notice, that I want to keep the in the legend the "missing values" indicator, regardless if that columns (aka date) has not NaNs(I'm collecting the figures and creating a GIF).

```
for i in geo_cases.iloc[:,:-2]:
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 12))
   # Set the global map 
   world.plot(color = '#e5e3e6', ax = ax, edgecolor = 'w', linewidth = 0.8)
   # set out map 
   geo_cases.plot(column = geo_cases[i], ax =ax, cmap = 'RdPu', legend = True, alpha = .4,
          linewidth = 0.3, edgecolor = 'w', categorical = True, missing_kwds={
        "color": "lightgrey",
        "edgecolor": "red",
        "hatch": "///",
        "label": "Missing values"})
```

[image: Error]

Comment: If there is no NaN, it cannot be expressed in the legend because NA data is not colored. If you want to do all of the above in a single piece of code... consider using the trick. Create a virtual shape outside the range you want to output, and add a row with the value as NAN. You can show only the range you want to express using (ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx), ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy) . Alternatively, you can put a small polygon in the drawing that is not really noticeable in the expression within the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making another polygone with missing vlaues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).